# Arrange exceptions in a list by some criteria

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting, index

I have some dataset, which is supposed to have $30000$ in the last column, and I want to find the elements that break this, and arrange them numerically while mantaining the index. What I'm currently doing is finding the exceptions and the indexes separately, then threading and sorting.

```
nums = Cases[data[[All, -1]], Except[30000]];
index = Flatten@Position[data[[All, -1]], _?(# != 30000 &)];
Sort[Thread[{nums, index}], #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &]

{{121,200}, {969,37}, ..., {29618,70}, {29934,96}}
```

I tried to use `MapIndexed`, but it seemed slower and confusing to me. Is there a less convoluted way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:
`SortBy[MapIndexed[ If[# != 30000, {#, First@#2}, Nothing] &, Last/@data ],First]`

A little less compact, but equivalent:

```
myTest[number_,index_]:=If[ number != 30000, {number,index},Nothing];
exceptions=MapIndexed[myTest[#,First[#2]]&,data[[All,-1]]];
exceptions=SortBy[exceptions,First]
```

`MapIndexed` supplies the index as `#2` for you to use in your function, but it comes as a list, so you have remove the head with `First`.

You could also use `Position` more directly:

```
exceptions = {Extract[Last /@ data, #], First@#} & /@ Position[Last /@ data, x_ /; x != 30000]
exceptions = SortBy[exceptions,First]
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be of some help.

```
list = data[[All, -1]]; 
Sort@Select[Thread[# -> Range[Length@list]] &@list /. Rule -> List, First[#] != 30000 &]
```

I took this as the example data:

```
data = Partition[Riffle[RandomChoice[{"A", "B"}, 10^6], 
    RandomChoice[Range[29000, 31000], 10^6]], {2}];
```

My code gave 3.2 seconds for `RepeatedTiming` and yours comes to around 24 seconds. A minor improvement.